# How to pass arguments to memcheck with ctest?

Tags: command-line, cmake, valgrind, ctest, memcheck

I want to use ctest from the command line to run my tests with memcheck and pass in arguments for the memcheck command.

I can run `ctest -R my_test` to run my test, and I can even run `ctest -R my_test -T memcheck` to run it through memcheck.

But I can't seem to find a way to pass arguments to that memcheck command, like `--leak-check=full` or `--suppressions=/path/to/file`.

After reading ctest's documentation I've tried using the `-D` option with `CTEST_MEMCHECK_COMMAND_OPTIONS` and `MEMCHECK_COMMAND_OPTIONS`. I also tried setting these as environment variables. None of my attempts produced any different test command. It's always:

```
Memory check command: /path/to/valgrind "--log-file=/path/to/build/Testing/Temporary/MemoryChecker.7.log" "-q" "--tool=memcheck" "--leak-check=yes" "--show-reachable=yes" "--num-callers=50"
```

How can I control the memcheck command from the ctest command line?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**TL;DR**

```
ctest --overwrite MemoryCheckCommandOptions="--leak-check=full --error-exitcode=100" \
      --overwrite MemoryCheckSuppressionFile=/path/to/valgrind.suppressions \
      -T memcheck
```

### Explanation

I finally found the right way to override such variables, but unfortunately it's not easy to understand this from the documentation.
So, to help the next poor soul that needs to deal with this, here is my understanding of the various ways to set options for `memcheck`.

In a `CTestConfig.cmake` in you top-level source dir, or in a `CMakeLists.txt` (*before* calling `include(CTest)`), you can set `MEMORYCHECK_COMMAND_OPTIONS` or `MEMORYCHECK_SUPPRESSIONS_FILE`.
When you `include(CTest)`, CMake will generate a `DartConfiguration.tcl` in your build directory and setting the aforementioned variables will populate `MemoryCheckCommandOptions` and `MemoryCheckSuppressionFile` respectively in this file.
This is the file that `ctest` parses in your build directory to populate its internal variables for running the `memcheck` step.
So, if you'd like to set you project's options for memcheck during cmake configuration, this is the way to got.

If instead you'd like to modify these options after you already have a properly configured build directory, you can:

1. Modify the DartConfiguration.tcl directly, but note that this will be overwritten if cmake runs again, since this file is regenerated each time cmake runs.
2. Use the ctest `--overwrite` command-line option to set these memcheck options just for that run.

### Notes

1. I've seen [mentions](https://github.com/nlohmann/json/issues/1030) online of a `CMAKE_MEMORYCHECK_COMMAND_OPTIONS` variable. I have no idea what this variable is and I don't think cmake is aware of it in any way.
2. Setting `CTEST_MEMORYCHECK_COMMAND_OPTIONS` (the variable that is actually [documented](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CTEST_MEMORYCHECK_COMMAND_OPTIONS.html) in the cmake docs) in your `CTestConfig.cmake` or `CMakeLists.txt` has no effect. It seems this variable only works in ["CTest Client Scripts"](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/ctest/Scripting-Of-CTest), which I have never used.
3. Unfortunately, both `MEMORYCHECK_COMMAND_OPTIONS` and `MEMORYCHECK_SUPPRESSIONS_FILE` aren't documented explicitly in [cmake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-variables.7.html#variables-for-ctest), only indirectly, in [ctest](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/ctest.1.html#ctest-memcheck-step) documentation and the [Testing With CTest](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/ctest/Testing-With-CTest#dynamic-analysis) tutorial.

When `ctest` is run in the build, it parses the  file to populate its internal variables:
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/ctest.1.html#dashboard-client-via-ctest-command-line
It's not clear to me how this interacts with

Comment: +1 the `overwrite MemoryCheckSuppressionFile=/path/to/valgrind.suppressions` is not very useful because it needs an absolute path. I found yet no equivalent to having `set(MEMORYCHECK_SUPPRESSIONS_FILE "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/.valgrind-suppressions")` in the Cmake file.