# How to let CMake / CTest memcheck exit with status code 1 on failure?

Tags: c, cmake, valgrind, ctest

I want to use ctest to run my tests with valgrind.
Thus I have written the following in my cmake file:

```
include(CTest)

find_program(MEMORYCHECK_COMMAND valgrind)
set(MEMORYCHECK_COMMAND_OPTIONS "--leak-check=full --error-exitcode=1")
set(MEMORYCHECK_SUPPRESSIONS_FILE "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/.valgrind-suppressions")
```

This seems to work. When I run `ctest -D ExperimentalMemCheck .` on a leaking program it shows me that it has found memory leaks, however does not exit with status != 0.

How can I get a exit code 1 on failure?

Comment: Do you use `MEMORYCHECK_COMMAND_OPTIONS` variable in any way?

Comment: Only in the way as shown in the example.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this already?

Answer (score 4):

The critical thing is that you put `set(MEMORYCHECK_COMMAND_OPTIONS "--error-exitcode=1")` ABOVE the `include(CTest)` call. The variable is apparently only taken into account when first including CTest and has no effect when setting it after including CTest.

When then calling `ctest -T memcheck`, the command correctly exits with a non-zero exit status.

Also see this questions for reference: [How to pass arguments to memcheck with ctest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52730994/how-to-pass-arguments-to-memcheck-with-ctest)

Comment: Are you sure that CTest is not included further up (or in another) CMakeLists.txt? Maybe try to reduce your CMakeLists.txt as far as possible or try it on a sample project, should work just fine.

Answer (score -1):

By default, valgrind memcheck exits with an error for leak kinds definite and possible.

You might want to have more leak kinds causing an error exit,
by using --errors-for-leak-kinds:

> ```
> --errors-for-leak-kinds=kind1,kind2,..  which leak kinds are errors?
>                                         [definite,possible]
>     where kind is one of:
>       definite indirect possible reachable all none
> ```

Comment: The problem is not valgrind. If I run valgrind manually I get the correct exit status. I want ctest to return a non zero exit status.